# unit testing nested objects in javascript/node

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, oop, elasticsearch

I have an object called NetFlowStorage that contains methods to access a specific elasticsearch index.  My constructor looks like:

```
function NetFlowStorage() {
    this.host = 'localhost:9200';
    this.shards = '4';
    this.replicas = '0';
    this.index_name = 'flow_track2';
    this.client = null;
}
```

Inside of the object I have a method called connect which, when called, will make the connection and store the elasticsearch client object in the `this.client` property (if there isn't one already there).  This way all of the object methods can get access to the elasticsearch client by using `this.client`

First question, is this an appropriate pattern?  If not, what is preferable?

Second question (and the one that drove me here), how would I mock calls to things like `this.client.index({})` I'm just starting to mess around with unit testing and mocks under node/js so I don't really have a preference in terms of framework (currently using mocha/chai/sinon)

Full code is [here](https://github.com/skarfacegc/FlowTrack2/blob/master/lib/NetFlowStorage.js) if you want to see in more detail.

Comment: This article might be of interest http://www.clock.co.uk/blog/tools-for-unit-testing-and-quality-assurance-in-node-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like this I would use [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

You want to decouple the `NetFlowStorage` class from the actual elasticsearch client:

```
function NetFlowStorage(esClient) {
    this.host = 'localhost:9200';
    this.shards = '4';
    this.replicas = '0';
    this.index_name = 'flow_track2';

    // if you don't wanna share connections across several instances
    // you can instantiate the client here otherwise you can pass the
    // client instance
    this.client = esClient; // or new esClient({ host: this.host })
}
```

This way you won't even need the **elasticsearch** as part of the node module and even share a connection across more than one instance (or not?)

This decoupling will also make it easier to mock the `esClient` as you would inject the mock elasticsearch client in the test itself.

Comment: Is this the preferred pattern for this type of thing?

Comment: I would say it's a good way of solving it. You can then abstract all this another level and have an `EsNetFlowStorage` class that extends a base `NetFlowStorage` class with an **elasticsearch** client and a `RedisNetFlowStorage` class if you wanna have a redis client. You'll just need to inject a different client

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should pass a config object and a connection object to the method.
So if you would use Jasmine for testing for example you could pass a spy

```
 var client = {index:function(){}}
 spyOn(client, 'index');
....
expect(client.index)toHaveBeenCalled();
```

and to pass it at some point with injection or a singleton to the SUT